# Why is my rotated SVG shifted?

Tags: svg, rotation

I try to build a reflection of my text with gradient. But the reflection (the second text) has an off set and by applying the rotation the letters are shifting.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="1000"     height="140"  viewBox="0 0 1000 140">
<text x="260" y="70" font-size="60" fill=" #888888" style="text-anchor: right">Multimediale Kunst</text>
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000000" />
    <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#666666" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs> 
<text rotate="180"  x="310"  y="80" font-size="60" fill="url(#linearGradient)" style="text-anchor: right">Multimediale Kunst</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `rotate` attribute rotates individual start points. So wider characters end up further away from narrow characters and vice-versa.

The `rotate` attribute is the wrong approach anyway.  If you want to vertically flip the text, then you should use a `transform` that scales the object on the y axis by -1.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="1000"     height="140"  viewBox="0 0 1000 140">
<text x="260" y="70" font-size="60" fill=" #888888" style="text-anchor: right">Multimediale Kunst</text>
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000000" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#666666" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs> 
<text x="260"  y="-80" font-size="60" fill="url(#linearGradient)" style="text-anchor: right" transform="scale(1,-1)">Multimediale Kunst</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I thought svg would work on all browsers, but it looks to me as firefox would ignore the gradient?

Comment: For me, the gradient is working the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Are you sure?
The upper text is light grey(not gradient) and the one underneath shoud go from grey to black.

Comment: Yes. They look identical for me in Chrome and Firefox (on Win7)

Comment: Could you pls have a look at https://en.stephanundverena.de/ if you can see the gradient. Thanks.

Comment: The gradient is not working on either for me. That is because I updated the gradient values, but you haven't in your version.  Note that the `offset` attributes in my version have changed. We are now flipping the text, so the gradient needs to be updated to compensate.